# Swift: SKConstraint for scale? (or equivalent) Stuttering

Tags: sprite-kit, constraints, scale, scaletransform

At the minute I'm using the `SKConstraint.positionX(rangex, y: rangey)` to confine my SKCameraNode within the game board I've created. This is nice because when you hit the boundary there's no stuttering. But my current way to cap the scale of the camera creates a stutter as it hits the bound as it goes past and pings back.

```
    @objc func zoomedView(_ sender:UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        if newCamera.xScale > 0.148{
            let pinch = SKAction.scale(by: 1/sender.scale, duration: 0.0)
            newCamera.run(pinch)
            sender.scale = 1.0
        } else {newCamera.setScale(0.148)}
    }
```

Is there an SKConstraint for scale (or equivalent) which is a better way to stop this stutter? Thanks :)

Comment: sounds frustrating... does your framerate actually drop? And is this on simulator or on a device?

Comment: @Fluidity It's not framerate dropping, it's happening because I can zoom past the bound, then it resets, so every time the function is called because the pinchgesture can go past the bound, it does, then the next time, it resets it.

Comment: @Fluidity the only thing I've thought of is that it's not in the draw loop, it's only when the function is called, so if I were to put it in the draw loop it might work, but I've not had time to test.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by draw loop... draw is a function called by SpriteKit at the of the game-loop...

Comment: if you could put a sample project for us to look at that would be helpful. trying to recreate the issue on our own is difficult.

Comment: The problem is the pinch gesture lies outside of SpriteKit, so it does not adhere to the Spritekit timeline.  Instead of immediately setting your scale, create a variable so that it can set the scale during your update loop, or use `SKAction.scale(to:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct SKConstraint equivalent for scale, however the reason you're experiencing the stuttering is as you go over the bound it snaps back the next time the function is called, rather before a frame is rendered, so theoretically you could zoom in massively instantaneously, and stay there until you activate the zoom function again.

A way to create an equivalent is to put the code checking whether the scale is greater than x in the rendering loop as outlined [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skscene).
[image: RenderLoop Diagram]

So if you were to check at the last possible moment:

```
override func didFinishUpdate() {
    if newCamera.xScale < 0.148{
        newCamera.setScale(0.148)
    } else if newCamera.xScale > 10{
        newCamera.setScale(10)
    }
}
```